# Single rewrite rule for http to https redirection and trailing slash removal

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, redirect

I want to make single 301 redirect process for http to https and also trailing slash removal.

**http to https redirection method is**

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^80$
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

**Trailing slash removal method is**

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]
```

I want both these steps in a single step, Is it possible?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Yes, I know how to make these process as two steps. But i want to make in one step. I just tried by changing lot of rewrite rules and conditions. But no luck

Answer (score 0):

Try if the following rule works:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|off
RewriteCond http%1://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} ^(https?://)([^/]+)(/.*)/?$
RewriteRule ^ %1%2%3 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Hi, No that rule neither works for http to https nor trailing slash removal, but thanks for you idea.